# Spring boot 2 with Spring Security OAUTH2 shows 403 error after successfull login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring security oauth2 client and configured the app as follow

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=abcd
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=password
```

1. As I start the application, I must login with login link which redirects user to google login page.
2. Once successfully authenticated with google, the user is redirected to the web page again
3. In this page I can check the **Principale** object successfully, which contains user data including **access token**
4. **The problem is** when I try to do ajax call to one of my controllers it always return

> (403 Unauthorized)

I am stuck on this for more than a week and googled it many times with luck, since the autoconfiguration for oauth2 client is new in spring boot 2.

**Update**

I believe **CORS** is out of the reasons because the ajax calls are executed from within the web app itself, using same domain name, not from third party (like app)

Comment: Dear @dur, I totally agree with you, but in this case there is no code available because it is autoconfigured in Spring boot, it is simple put the above mentioned properties in the application./properties file and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, I found a solution. 
The solution is to override the security autoconfiguration in spring boot 2 for OAuth client. 
I wrote the following Security Config class

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()

                    .oauth2Login();
    }

}
```

And thanks for every one who tried to help.

Comment: Also mark your client security configuration as `@EnableOAuth2Client` and make sure the `.oauth2Login()` is present as noted by @Muhannad A.Alhariri since the client will need to authenticate it needs a way to redirect to the authorization server to check the roles or authorities given to the authenticated user. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

***Steps I took to debug and fix:***

Enabled log for package:
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

I found there were issue with csrf because by default csrf Filter was applied.

I then disabled csrf from HttpSecurityConfigurer.

```
            http
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable();
```

Comment: This spring documentation helped;
If an HTTP 403 Forbidden is returned for HTTP POST, but works for HTTP GET then the issue is most likely related to CSRF. Either provide the CSRF Token or disable CSRF protection (not recommended).